# Want to compare a binding value from object to mainWindow.Label.Content (with XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

having an XAMl-Button, which should appear conditionally;
Condition is like: is object owner same as player -> so Button.Content = sell, else Button.Content = buy

```
<Button Name="cmdTrade" Width="100" Margin="2" >
    <Button.Style>
         <Style.TargetType="Button">
               <Setter Property="Content" Value="Buy" />
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                     <Style.Triggers>
                          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Inhaber}" Value=MainWindow.lblPlayer.Content >
                               <Setter Property="Content" Value="Sell" />
                               <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCoral" />
                          </DataTrigger>
                     </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Instead of comparing `Inhaber` value with `MainWindow.lblPlayer.Content` consider to add dedicated property  `bool IsOwnerSameAsPlayer` (with notification) to view model and simply bind `DataTrigger` to it.

Comment: Or use a MultiBinding.

Comment: thanks for your help - will try these ways